# Hibernate OneToOne behaving like ManyToOne

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

I have these classes:

```
public class Person {

    @Id
    private int personId;

    @OneToOne
    private SomeOtherId someOtherId;
}

public class SomeOtherId {
     @Id 
     private int someId;

     // other fields
}
```

I did this:

```
Person person1 = new Person(1);
SomeOtherId someOtherId = new SomeOtherId(100);
person1.setSomeOtherId(someOtherId);
//Update the database so that both the above entities are persisted

Person person2 = new Person(2);
person2.setSomeOtherId(someOtherId);
//Update the database so that person2 is persisted
```

It all works! And it assigns someOtherId to both the person entities which it shouldn't as the relationship is OneToOne. Each person has to have a unique SomeOtherId. In database also, I can see a single entity for SomeOtherId and id of that mapped to two Persons.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a @JoinColumn and set the unique attribute to true

Comment: This works..but why does it require another annotation for this? Shouldn't OneToOne suffice?

Comment: Hibernate provide 3 ways to create a one to one relationship: first using a foreign key column, a second using a join table and the third using shared primary key.